# NSInvalidArgumentException while Presenting ModalView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, messageui

Exception Message:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: 
Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <Navigator: 0x1bed0d0>.
```

Here is my code:

```
    partial void BtnTest (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender)
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController view = new MFMailComposeViewController();
        view.SetToRecipients(new string[]{"blubb@blubb.de"});
        view.SetMessageBody("Hier steht nun der zusammengestellt text :)", false);
        //view.MailComposeDelegate = new CustomMailComposeDelegate();
        view.SetSubject("Test");

        view.Finished += (s,e)=>
                     {
                            this.NavigationController.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
        };

        this.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>
        {
            this.NavigationController.PresentModalViewController(view, true);
        });

    }
```

It works on iPad Emulator but not on the Device.

Comment: If @Jason answer did not work then please post the complete stacktrace / crash log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your device configured to send emails ? note that even if it is you should not consider it will be the case on every user devices.

IWO you should call `MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail` like this is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) by Apple. Two important quotes:

> you must always check to see if the current device is configured to send email at all using the canSendMail method

and

> You should not attempt to use this interface if the canSendMail method returns NO.

Example:

```
   if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail) {
       ... your code ...
   } else {
       ... show warning, like an UIAlertView
   }
```

Comment: Oh dear i forgot to configure a EmailAccount on the iPad. Problem solved. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Move this declaration outside of your method.  It is most likely getting GC as soon as it goes out of scope.

```
MFMailComposeViewController view;
```